# How to write VBA user defined function to take array argument from IF with ctrl+shift+enter?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I created a function called *test*

```
Function test(a() As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Type: "; TypeName(a)
    Debug.Print "lb: "; LBound(a)
    Debug.Print "ub: "; UBound(a)
    test = a(UBound(a))
End Function
```

It is okay when I type

```
=test({4,5,6,8,9})
```

in a cell. It returns 9.

Let's have some data on the worksheet.

```
   A  B
1  1  3
2  0  6
3  1  9
4  0  7
5  1  8
```

I type the below formula with ctrl+shift+enter in a cell.

```
{=test(IF(A1:A5=1,B1:B5))}
```

I think an array is passed into *test* but it doesn't work. It can return **LBound(a)** and **UBound(a)** as usual but **test = a(UBound(a))** fails.

What is the problem? How can I write a write VBA user defined function to take array argument from IF.

Comment: `=test{(IF(A1:A5=1,B1:B5))}` Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundimental difference between the two examples.  
`=test({4,5,6,8,9})` passes a 1-D array, and `{=test(IF(A1:A5=1,B1:B5))}` passes a 2-D array.  Your code is set up to process only 1-D arrays, so the second example fails.

How to fix this will depend entirely on what you actually want the UDF to do.  For the example, You could coerce the input to 1-D using Transpose, but that's probably to limited for the general case.  Might be better to test in parameter to determine its dimension and process accordingly

Comment: Just a follow-up question, how can I know this is a 2-D array? and what index is used in this array?

Comment: There are lots of good array functions on cpearson.com including finding the dimension of an array.  To make it work for just 2-D try `test = a(UBound(a,1))`